# php composer project class not found

Tags: php, composer-php

Hi I try to use this composer package:

https://github.com/stevenmaguire/oauth2-microsoft

Code looks like this at the moment:

```
use \Stevenmaguire\OAuth2\Client\Provider\Microsoft;

$provider = new Microsoft([
    // Required
    'clientId'                  => '',
    'clientSecret'              => '',
    'redirectUri'               => 'http://localhost/microsoftToDo/app/microsoft.php',
    // Optional
    'urlAuthorize'              => 'https://login.windows.net/common/oauth2/authorize',
    'urlAccessToken'            => 'https://login.windows.net/common/oauth2/token',
    'urlResourceOwnerDetails'   => 'https://outlook.office.com/api/v1.0/me'
]);
```

when I run the project I got this error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Stevenmaguire\OAuth2\Client\Provider\Microsoft' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\microsoftToDo\src\microsoft.php:12 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\microsoftToDo\src\microsoft.php on line 12
```

Folder structure is:

[image]

What Is my issue in this case? thanks in advance.

Comment: show your composer.json file.

Comment: you may not properly installed the package try `composer require stevenmaguire/oauth2-microsoft`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you haven't installed it properly with composer, if you had that Stevenmaguire folder would be inside a vendor folder.

From your projects root run...

`composer require stevenmaguire/oauth2-microsoft`

Then if you see a vendor folder it has worked. You will also need to require `vendor/autoload.php` in your code to autoload that class.